# Get All Taxonomy Terms From Get_terms Array With Specific Array Key

Tags: terms, multi-taxonomy-query

I have below code to extract all terms from multiple taxonomies,

```
$taxonomies = array('ingredients','category','course');
                $args = array(
                    'hide_empty' => 0
                );
                $terms = get_terms( $taxonomies, $args);
                $AutoComplete = array();

                foreach($terms as $key => $value) {
                    array_push($AutoComplete[$value->taxonomy] = [$value->name]);
                }
                    echo "<pre>";
                    echo json_encode($AutoComplete);
                    echo "</pre>";
            ?>
```

This works fine and gives me the result of

```
{"ingredients":["Cumin Seeds"],"category":["Uncategorized"],"course":["Main Course"]}
```

The issue is that the all taxonomies have multiple terms but it returns only one - the last term.

Am I missing any this here?

Thanks
Saq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is at **array_push($AutoComplete[$value->taxonomy] = [$value->name]);**

Can you replace it with this code and test once?

```
$AutoComplete[$value->taxonomy][] = [$value->name];
```

Comment: Nearly there, I managed the fix with the help of your code, `$AutoComplete[$value->taxonomy][] = $value->name;`